# how to make to stop on specific number when button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<label id="minutes">0</label>
<label id="seconds">0</label>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
        var totalSeconds = 0;
        setInterval(setTime, 150);

        function setTime()
        {
            ++totalSeconds;
            secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%10);
        }

        function pad(val)
        {
            var valString = val + "";
            if(valString.length < 1)
            {
                return "0" + valString;
            }
            else
            {
                return valString;
            }
        }
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
        var totalSeconds = 0;
        setInterval(setTime, 100);

        function setTime()
        {
            minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%6);
        }

        function pad(val)
        {
            var valString = val + "";
            if(valString.length < 1)
            {
                return "0" + valString;
            }
            else
            {
                return valString;
            }
        }
    </script>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction1() {
      var a = document.getElementById("minutes");
      var b = document.getElementById("seconds");

     dont' know what should i write in here
    </script>
    
    <button onclick="myFuntion1">click</button>

</body>
<html>
```

i wanna make stop button in specific number.
so whenever you clicked the button
the countup stop on 15.
any help will be so appreciated. :)

thanks

--repeat cause it said i can't upload this question because of not enough detail.

i wanna make stop button in specific number.
so whenever you clicked the button
the countup stop on 15.
any help will be so appreciated. :)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Print out the `1` and `5`.
2. Stop the timer. (You should assign a variable to each timer first)

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<label id="minutes">0</label>
<label id="seconds">0</label>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
        var totalSeconds = 0;
        var t1 = setInterval(setTime, 150);

        function setTime()
        {
            ++totalSeconds;
            secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%10);
        }

        function pad(val)
        {
            var valString = val + "";
            if(valString.length < 1)
            {
                return "0" + valString;
            }
            else
            {
                return valString;
            }
        }
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
        var totalSeconds = 0;
        var t2 = setInterval(setTime, 100);

        function setTime()
        {
            minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%6);
        }

        function pad(val)
        {
            var valString = val + "";
            if(valString.length < 1)
            {
                return "0" + valString;
            }
            else
            {
                return valString;
            }
        }
    </script>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction1() {
      document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = '1';
      document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = '5';
      clearInterval(t1);
      clearInterval(t2);
    }
    </script>
    
    <button onclick="myFunction1()">click</button>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: thank you sooo much Chaska!!! have a great day!!! thanks a lot!!! :D